# WPF control stretching issue

Tags: wpf

I have a `DataGrid` in a `Grid` in a `TabItem`:

```
<TabItem Header="SomeHeader">
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition SharedSizeGroup="TabHeight" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="TabWidth"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <DataGrid Margin="10" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                  VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                  IsReadOnly="True" 
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</TabItem>
```

Problem is that `DataGrid` refuses to size to the containing `Grid`. What prevents it from doing so?

Comment: You don't have any columns in that datagrid and you turned off autogenerate which would have generated them. And no itemssource bound.

Comment: Can you please show your other Grids, where you apply the shared size groups and where you set the shared size scope?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Grid` shares its row and column sizes with the shared size groups `TabWidth` and `TabHeight`. Consequently, the sizes of the row and column that contain the `DataGrid` are determined among all `Grid`s that share the same groups and are located in the same grid size scope like this:

- Absolute values take precedence over `Auto`, so the largest *explicit* column size in the group wins, even if all others are defined as `Auto`
- If all rows / columns are `Auto`-sized, the largest wins
- Star-sizes (`*`) are treated as `Auto` (the *default* width of a column is `1*`, so this rule applies then, too)

To clarify, the `DataGrid` is sized to fit its assigned row and column within the `Grid`, not the size of the `Grid` itself. If you want to size it to the containing tab, the `Grid` is redundant. Applying both a shared size to a row or a column and sizing it to fill its parent are opposing goals, choose one.